# Ruby Gemfile does not match Ruby Version, but does match ruby -v output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

I have a rails app and I am kinda new rails.

My main issue is that I am on a production server and cannot run `bundle`.
It gives this error:

`Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.7`

So, I have tried to use rbenv, but it was not sucessful as can be seen below.

```
$:/home/deploy/my-app/current$ rbenv global 2.1.7

$:/home/deploy/my-app/current$ bundle
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.7

$:/home/deploy/my-app/current$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.7p400 (2015-08-18 revision 51632) [x86_64-linux]
```

Using RVM seems to be what others are using in other questions, but I really just want one version of ruby running (the one that is specified)

This server is going to be the production but is currently not live.

**EDIT 1:** `gem install bundler`

I have tried installing bundle while in ruby 2.1.7 but this did not work.

Here is what I did:

```
$:/home/deploy/my-app/current$  ruby -v
ruby 2.1.7p400 (2015-08-18 revision 51632) [x86_64-linux]
$:/home/deploy/my-app/current$  gem install bundler 
Fetching: bundler-1.11.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.11.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.11.2
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.11.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 4 seconds
1 gem installed
$:/home/deploy/my-app/current$  bundle
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.7
```

**EDIT 2** `which bundle`

```
 $:/home/deploy/my-app/current$ which bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

Comment: What does `which bundle` show? It could be that you don’t have Bundler installed in 2.1.7, but it is in 1.9.3 (which I suspect is the version of Ruby provided by the OS), and this version is being found when you run `bundle`. You might just need to `gem install bundler` in 2.1.7.

Comment: `which bundle` gives:  /usr/local/bin/bundle @matt

Comment: Are you using Bash as your shell? After installing bundler, try running `hash -r` (or alternatively start a new session). Your shell may have cached the path to the old version of `bundle`, so you may still be getting it instead of the new one.

Comment: I think that may have been the issue, I just recently got it working and I think it was a result of my restarting the terminal. @matt

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a .ruby-version file, specifying the ruby version 2.1.7.
When you enter the project directory, the rbenv will use the correct ruby version.
After that, reenter the project directory and execute `bundle exec bundle`.

Comment: do you know where i'd put the .ruby-version file?

Comment: @Rorschach, You should put .ruby-version file in home directory of rails app. Source: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version